# Алгоритм пересечения маршрутов

Tags: алгоритм

Дано: Условный транспортер перемещает объект между точками остановки(время перемещения известно), на точках задано время которое объект должен там находиться(именно столько сколько задано, не больше и не меньше), во время нахождения объекта на точке транспортер свободен. В какой-то момент времени пользователь желает запустить другой объект с заданным маршрутом. Требуется проверить возможность обработки нового объекта транспортером и в случае невозможности, рассчитать через какой промежуток времени это будет возможно.

P.S. На точке остановки может находиться только один объект

**Обновление**

1. Транспортер движется по прямой вперед/назад.
2. Он перемещает объект по заданным точкам на прямой по заданному маршруту. Когда он привозит объект на заданную точку, то он оставляет его там на заданное время, пока объект находится на точке, транспортер волен делать все что хочет.
3. Запускаются все объекты с одной точки и в конце в нее же возвращаются
4. Важно! Объект должен находиться на точке строго заданное в маршруте время.
5. В одной точке одновременно может находиться только один объект.

Была идея рассмотреть все точки как массив и на основании маршрута рассчитывать когда они будут заняты и когда освободятся, и на основании этого при появлении следующего объекта рассчитывать тоже самое для него и смотреть не пересекутся ли они, но там не понятно как рассчитать промежуток когда можно запустить новый объект.

Comment: Тут явно можно приспособить алгоритм Дейкстры про поиск пути.

Comment: Возможно я не совсем правильно понимаю, но маршрут нам известен и менять его нельзя.

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста свой вопрос!

Comment: @AntonPopov, честно говоря саму задачу я тоже не доконца понимаю. Как движется транспортер, только по прямой или это сеть путей? Что происходит с объектом, который он пермещает - он его бесконечно возит или из А в Б? Если транспортер довез объект, он возвращается на базу? С какой точки можно запускать новый объект (с одной все или с произвольной)?